# angular test not executing directive code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having some trouble testing angular directives.  Here's what I'm experiencing.  I've got karma set up to run my tests.  It appears that the link code within the directive (the section with console log "kicking off calculations") never actually fires.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  The test works as I'd expect -- except when I get down to imageNode.style -- there's nothing in there.  There are no styles assigned to the image.  Why is the directive code not being fired?  Any ideas?

This is my module code.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  // sets narrower side of image to width of parent div
  // used in sjwUserImage
  angular.module('sjw.util', [])
    .directive('imgFit', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
          element.bind('load', function(e) {
            console.log('kicking off calculations...');
            console.log(element);
            var parentWidth = element.parent().width();

            if (this.naturalHeight > this.naturalWidth) {
              // not horizontal or square
              this.width = parentWidth;
            }
            else {
              this.height = parentWidth;
            }
          });
        }
      };
    });
})();
```

This is my test code.

```
describe('imgFit directive', function() {
  var compile;
  var scope;
  var directiveElem;

  console.log('loading sjw.util module...');
  beforeEach(function(done) {
    module('sjw.util', function() {
      console.log('completed loading module.');
    });

    inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
      angular.module('sjw.util');
      compile = $compile;
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      directiveElem = getCompiledElement();
      done();
    });
  });

  function getCompiledElement() {
    var myApp = angular.module('sjw.util');
    var elem = angular.element(
      '<div style="height:35px;width:35px">' +
        '<img ' +
          'ng-src="http://random_image_url" img-fit>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div style="height:35px;width:35px">' +
        '<img ' +
          'ng-src="http://random_image_url" img-fit>' +
      '</div>');
    var compiledDirective = compile(elem)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    return compiledDirective;
  }

  it('should assign width to parent width when image is square', function() {
    var squareImageParent = directiveElem[0];
    console.log(directiveElem);
    expect(squareImageParent).not.toBe(null);

    var imageNode = squareImageParent.childNodes[0];
    expect(imageNode).toBeDefined();
    console.log(imageNode);
    console.log(imageNode.style);
    //expect(imageNode.style.height == '35px').toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with some kind of synchronicity issue.  running setTimeout(done, 1000) causes the directive function to execute.  Any ideas what's causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have exorcised this demon.  My problem was with the directive itself.  My images weren't finishing loading within the headless browser I'm using.  So the 'load' event in 'imgFit.link' would never fire.  Obviously a problem.  That's why inserting my timeout (in comment above) was helping.  It allowed the images to finish loading.  Ugly hack, but seems like I have no way of knowing when phantom's going to load the images.

```
  beforeEach(function(done) {
    module('sjw.util');

    inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
      compile = $compile;
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      directiveElem = getCompiledElement();

      // wait for the images to finish loading.
      setTimeout(done, 2000);
    });
  });
```